# Tikz externalize crashes on texlive using MWE

Tags: tikz-pgf, externalize

If I run the MWE for tikz with externalize from their documentation: https://tikz.dev/library-external#sec-52.4 , I get the following error:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'lualatex -halt-on-error -inter action=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test}\input{ test}"' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -halt-on-error
-interact ion=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test}\input{tes t}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'test-figure0' (expected one of .pd f:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdfl atex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' o r something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can b e found in 'test-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the pic ture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...

l.16 \end{tikzpicture}
```

I am running up-to-date Ubuntu 2022/WSL and I have texlive 2022/dev/Debian (texlive-fullscheme) installed.
I compile the document with lualatex in version 1.14.0.
As soon as I disable \tikzexternalize it compiles.

I also tried the suggestion made here: https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=18746
to add

```
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex
        \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode --extra-mem-top=3000000
        -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

But it did not result in a solution to my problem. I know that the MWE worked for a long time, but since a few weeks it is not working anymore.

Has someone ideas how to solve the issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just as a side note: Under win11 and up-to-date miktex it compiles without errors.

Comment: How are you compiling your main document? Is `-shell-escape` enabled? Is there a log file you can inspect?

Comment: Exactly how do you compile this? I tried with `lualatex -shell-escape file.tex` on Upstream TeXLive 2022. Compiled just fine. I'm just running the updater to make sure I have the latest versions.

Comment: Okay. Yes, it solves the problem. Coming from windows and using lualatex with working compilation under miktex I thought that this command is not the issue.
Thanks for your support

Comment: Updated Upstream TeXLive 2022, still works just fine on the example linked to in the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments and due to an issue not evident in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`lualatex -shell-escape file.tex` as mentioned in the comments solves the problem even if `-shell-escape` is not necessary under windows with miktex.

Comment: what do you mean by "even if -shell-escape is not necessary under windows with miktex."??  shell operations are blocked on windows just as they are on linux. As documented, you need `--shell-escape` here.

Comment: if --shell-escape is not needed under miktex, then something is wrong with your miktex installation. (it needs -shell-escape for me).

Comment: but there is an open bug in the external library: If a pdf for the figure is already present (e.g. from some earlier test or compilation), tikz will happily use that if `--shell-escape` is not used, even if the code for the figure changed in the meantime. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1137